# Create dynamic form elements based on select change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

Have a requirement to prompt the user for a (configurable) set of inputs, mainly textboxes, based on their choice from a list of options in a select field.  I dont want to define all of the inputs and then show/hide different groups, but rather inject these components into the UI based on the users selection.  I dont' think Ive seen anything like this yet without defining all the input elements ahead of time.

I am thinking to keep the definition of the inputs in either json or a model class.

In other word, something like in this UI, but based on the users selection for "Select file type", they might be presented with 5 inputs or only 4 or 3 etc.

Other than using jQuery to show/hide different groups of inputs based on the users selection, what other way could a "dynamic" form be implemented like this?

[image]

Comment: Hi [bitshift](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3206983/bitshift),
Aren't you satisfied with my proposed solution?
If so am I misuderstanding your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to add all five inputs to your UI, and to use CSS-Classes to hide/display the 2 last inputs (as the 3 others are always needed and therefore always displayed) depending on the user's choice from the list of options.

```
<label>Please select an option</label>
<select id="choice">
  <option value="3">3 Inputs</option>
  <option value="4">4 Inputs</option>
  <option value="5">5 Inputs</option>    
</select>
<button id="btn">Go</button>
<br>    
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div>
    <label for="input-001">Input 001</label>
    <input type="text" id="input-001" name="input-001">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="input-002">Input 002</label>
    <input type="password" id="input-002" name="input-002">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="input-003">Input 003</label>
    <input type="date" id="input-003" name="input-003">
  </div>
  <div id="div-004">
    <label for="input-004">Input 004</label>
    <input type="email" id="input-004" name="input-004">
  </div>
  <div id="div-005">
    <label for="input-005">Input 005</label>
    <input type="file" name="input-005">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Add a **css**-class:

```
.optional {
  display: none;
  /*visibility: hidden;*/ /*you may/nedd to use visibility instead of display*/
}
```

Add a event-handler to the button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn" ).click(function(){
      let choice = $("#choice").val();
      if (choice == 3) {
        console.log("hide input-004 & input-005 ");
        $("#div-004").addClass("optional");
        $("#div-005").addClass("optional");
      } else if(choice == 4) {
        console.log("hide input-005 & display input-004 ");
        $("#div-004").removeClass("optional");
        $("#div-005").addClass("optional");
      } else if(choice == 5) {
        $("#div-004").removeClass("optional");
        $("#div-005").removeClass("optional");
      }
    })
})
```

Here is a [working fiddle example](https://codepen.io/meziano/pen/dyoWbGz)